# Is there a way in PhpStorm to scroll viewport without moving caret?

Tags: navigation, phpstorm

I want to keep the caret on the current line, but move the viewport up or down in the code, allowing me to stay on the current line but see a few more lines above the top of screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Scroll Up` and `Scroll Down` actions. On Windows, using Default keymap, they will be linked to <kbd>Ctrl + Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl + Down</kbd> accordingly.

On Linux/Mac .. or using any other keymap -- just look for those actions in `Settings/Preferences | Keyamp` -- use search field and type `scroll` to filter the list:

[image]